# Shortest way to convert these bytes to int in python?

Tags: python

I'm converting the following string to it's unsigned integer representation:

`str = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xFF'`

I can use `struct.unpack('8B', str)` to get the tuple representation `(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,255)`, but what's the quickest/easiest way to convert this tuple to an int?

Right now, my code is

```
def unpack_str(s):
  i = r = 0
  for b in reversed(struct.unpack('8B', s)):
    r += r*2**i
    i++
  return r
```

But this is long and ugly, for such a simple function! There must be a better way! Can any SO python gurus help me to trim this down and python-ify it?

Comment: psst! Your function will always return zero! Can you see why?

Comment: Also, `i++` is invalid syntax (as opposed to the equally meaningless, but more sneaky `++i` which runs but doesn't do anything).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> struct.unpack('>q', s)[0]
511
```

Answer (score 2):

Just unpack as a long long (64-bit integer):

```
struct.unpack('>Q', str)
```

`Q` = unsigned long long. Switch to `q` if the string represents a signed long long.

The `>` indicates big-endian byte order. Use `<` to indicate little-endian byte order.

Answer (score 0):

```
def unpack_str(bytes):
  return struct.unpack('<q',bytes)
```

Struct can deal with 8-byte long longs directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in practice, your "<" seems to be incorrect (gives me an answer in the millions, I assume this is for a signed longlong?)

Comment: @linked: `<` is for little-endian (i.e. rightmost bit is most most significant), `>` is for big-endian (i.e. leftmost bit is most significant). `q` is for (signed) `long long`.

Answer (score 0):

Have to agree with the `long and ugly` comment. Totally ignoring the struct.unpack Q/q option:

```
def unpack_str(s):
  r = 0
  for b in struct.unpack('8B', s):
    r = r * 256 + b
  return r
```

The second-last line could have used bit-bashing operators:

```
r = (r << 8) | b
```